# I Need to Allow only values between 0 -999 only in Jqgrid Edit Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

i am new to jqgrid , I need to Allow only values between 0 -999 only in Jqgrid Edit Form, 
I need to display Custom message "Please enter number between 0 and 999".

```
$(document).ready(function () {          

                $("#TableDataGrid").jqGrid({
                    url: '/DataHandler.ashx?MethodName=RulesGetAllData1',
                    datatype: "json",

                    colNames: ['ID', 'Rule','value'],
                    prmNames: { id: "ID" },
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'ID', hidden: true, key: true, index: 'ID', editoptions: { disabled: true }, width: 20, "sortable": true, sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                        {
                            name: 'RuleName', index: 'RuleName', width: 40, editable: true, sorttype: 'text',
                            searchoptions: {
                                sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'],
                                maxlength: 30, size: 30,
                                style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%;float:left"
                            },
                            searchrules: { required: true },
                            editrules: { required: true},
                            editoptions: { maxlength: 30, size: 30, disabled: true }

                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 40, editable: true, sorttype: 'integer', 
                            searchoptions: {
                                sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'],
                                maxlength: 5, size: 5,
                                style: "width:auto;padding:0;max-width:100%;float:left"
                            },
                            editoptions: { maxlength: 3, size: 5 },

    ,
                            searchrules: { required: true }


                        }                    

                    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

try to Put this code on editrules on which field you need to put validation

```
    editrules: {
                                required: true, custom: true, custom_func: function (value, colname) {
                                    if (value.indexOf('+') > -1 || value.indexOf('-') > -1
                                        || value.indexOf('.') > -1 || value.indexOf(' ') > -1)
                                        return [false, "Please enter number between 0 and 999"];

                                    if (isNaN(value))
                                        return [false, "Please enter number between 0 and 999"];
                                    else
                                        return [true, ""];
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks , this is what I was looking for. Worked perfectly

Comment: @AbdulSaleem If this answers your question then you should mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it helps future StackOverflow users.